# Fourier transform and inverse transform in opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

The **Fourier transform** and its **inverse transform** are implemented in C++ `OpenCV`. But I cannot obtain the correct result, and the image cannot be recovered via inverse transform. Is something wrong with the following code?

```
Mat transform(const Mat& src, int rows, int cols)
{
    complex<double> ci{ 0, 1 };
    vector<double> real_t;
    vector<double> imag_t;
    double row = static_cast_double(rows);
    double col = static_cast_double(cols);
    for (int u = 0; u < rows; u++)
    {
        for (int v = 0; v < cols; v++)
        {
            complex<double> tmp(0.0, 0.0);
            for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
            {
                complex<double> temp(0.0, 0.0);
                for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
                {
                    temp += exp(-2 * PI * (u * x / row + y * v / col) * ci) * static_cast_double(src.at<uchar>(x, y));
                }
                tmp += temp;
            }
            complex<double> tempor = tmp / sqrt(row * col);
            real_t.push_back(static_cast_float(tempor.real()));
            imag_t.push_back(static_cast_float(tempor.imag()));
        }
    }
    Mat s1(real_t);
    s1 = s1.reshape(0, rows);
    Mat s2(imag_t);
    s2 = s2.reshape(0, rows);
    Mat s[2] = { s1, s2 };
    Mat dst;
    merge(s, 2, dst);
    return dst;
}

Mat inverse(const Mat& src, int rows, int cols)
{
    assert(src.channels() == 2);
    vector<Mat> ft_mats;
    cv::split(src, ft_mats);
    complex<double> ci{ 0.0, 1.0 };
    vector<uchar> real_t, img_t;
    double row = static_cast_double(rows);
    double col = static_cast_double(cols);
    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
        {
            complex<double>sum{ 0.0, 0.0 };
            for (int u = 0; u < rows; u++)
            {   
                complex<double> tmp(0.0, 0.0);
                for (int v = 0; v < cols; v++)
                {
                    double rt = ft_mats[0].at<double>(u, v);
                    double it = ft_mats[1].at<double>(u, v);
                    complex<double> temp{ rt, it };
                    tmp += temp * exp(2 * PI * (u * x / row + v * y / col) * ci);
                }
                sum += tmp;
            }
            //sum /= sqrt(col * row);
            real_t.push_back(static_cast_uchar((sum.real())));
        }
    }
    Mat s1(real_t);
    s1 = s1.reshape(0, rows);
    return s1;
}
```

The original image:

[image]

The result of the Fourier transform:

[image]

Put the result of the above transform as the parameter into the function inverse:

[image]

It can be seen that the result of the inverse transform is totally different from the original image. How can I correct this? Thank you for your attention.

Update: The transform process is proved to be correct, and the original image can be obtained via idft in OpenCV. But the inverse function still cannot...I still don't know what is wrong after checking inverse function for many many times...

Comment: The problem likely is with `static_cast_uchar` in the inverse transform. Try without casting, creating a floating-point output. Then look at that to make sure it is correct and in the expected range. Casting values outside of the 0-255 range to a uchar does weird things!

Comment: I still cannot find what went wrong...It's so weird...

Comment: How are you displaying your floating-point image? Many viewers will cast to uint8, sometimes after multiplying by 255. You need to display the floating-point image as it is. Scale the min to 0 and max to 1, then display, or max to 255, or whatever your viewer utility expects. It helps if you post a [mre], rather than only code pieces.

Comment: Mat ift = inverse(ft, ft.rows, ft.cols); normalize(ift, ift, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX); namedWindow("IFT", WINDOW_NORMAL); resizeWindow("IFT", ift.rows, ift.cols); imshow("FT Inverse", ift); waitKey(0);